# Fixed div relative to another element

Tags: html, position, fixed

So I want to include a side legend that need so remain fixed on the screen. The problem is that I need it to position it relative to another element, in this case a table. I did put it on the right side but if I do it my way if I move to a larger screen it moves all to way to the edge of the screen which is annoying

```
<div style="position:relative;min-width:960px; max-width:1000px">
 <img src="img/untitled.png" style="position: fixed; right:0;" />
</div>
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" style="width: 800px; background-color: #E8E8E8;">
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right u want to hava a two tiled Screeen, on one side the navigation and on the other the tabel/content/whatever? Then I would work with %.

Step 1:
Create one DIV around all other elements:

`<div id="allContent">...</div>`

Step 2: 
Create a Style section in your header - thats mutch cleaner:

`<head>.. <style>[css]</style></head>`

Step 3:

Write tell the contDiv that it's the full size of the window (in the CSS section [CSS]):

```
#allContent{   position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width:100%; height: 100% }
```

Step 4:
Create 2 DIV's in the #allCont DIV which will be the left and the right side:

```
<div id="left"></div> <div id="right"></div>
```

Css:

```
#left{ position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 20%; height: 100% }
#right{ position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 80%; height: 100% }
```

now throw ur stuff in there..

**EDIT:**

For make the left side / navigation scroll with set the position of the left to fixed:

```
#left{ position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 20%; height: 100%}
```

now the left side / navigation will scroll with and the right will stay at position.

Comment: i think the issue is that OP wants a section to 'stick' to the screen and scroll down with the page, but then not extend all the way to the right side of the screen when on larger screens

Comment: i dont believe this will help, as the table is aligned to the center of the page. OP is trying to position a fixed element relative to the edge of the centered table

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for this is to hack around how a fix element works, by fixed positioning a container, and then absolutely positioning the element you want to be relative to the table.

Set you fixed element to have the same width as your table width. Something like:

**HTML**

```
<div id="fixedElemContainer">
    <div id="innerElem"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#fixedElemContainer{
    height:1px; /* make this 0 if you like, its really just so it doesnt cover the page content*/
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:960px;
    position:fixed;
    right:0; /* by setting both this will move the element to the middle when we have a max-width*/
    left:0;
}
#fixedElemContainer #innerElement{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```